# Replace Notepad with Notepad2 (or Notepad++)

Tags: windows-7, installation

What is the correct way to install Notepad2 (or some other equivalent) in Windows 7 so that it is executed when ***WindowsKey-R*** -> ***notepad*** is entered?

I've tried creating shortcuts in C:\windows\System32 or replacing Notepad.exe. Both failed due to permissions issues.

Comment: Just curious, if its only permission issues, then why not change the permissions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Never replace actual system files.** This causes more problems than the actual benefit.

A build of Notepad2 using "Image File Execution Options\Debugger" (a feature in Windows usually used to automatically attach debuggers on processes by substituting a process for another) to replace the original Notepad is available at this URL:

> http://code.kliu.org/misc/notepad2/

It is way safer than replacing notepad, and doesn't require Windows File Protection to be disable or circumvented. Works on any version of Windows >= XP.

Answer (score 2):

Found it... leaving the question up in case others find it useful

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/showthread.php?t=35&page=2

Comment: -1 for link only answer (and it's better to use the image file execution method anyway)

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution right on [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) webpage.

[Replacing Notepad in Windows Vista](http://www.mattberther.com/2006/11/19/replacing-notepad-in-windows-vista/)

> 1. Download and extract **Notepad2**.
> 2. Rename **Notepad2.exe** to **notepad.exe**.
> 3. Find **c:\windows\notepad.exe** and **c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe** and set the owner to ‘**Administrators**’, and grant **Administrators full control**.
> 4. Using Windows Explorer, drag and drop the renamed **notepad2.exe** to **c:\windows** and **c:\windows\system32**.

Just don't forget to grant 'Administrators' full control.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the notepad file notepad2's file (renaming is a good option) in 3 directories:

```
WINDOWS
WINDOWS/SYSTEM32
WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/DLLCACHE
(start replacing them in reverse order, starting with ...DLLCACHE)
```

Put retry when Windows start complaining about it. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple:

1. go to Notepad++ dir and copy Notepad++.exe to notepad.exe but keep both in that dir
2. edit your path enviroment settings to include that dir but put in int the front of the settings for example:

   ```
   C:/Windows/system32;...
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   C:(PATH to dir of notepad++);C:/Windows/system32;...
   ```